# What is the accepted method of converting shininess to roughness, and vice versa?

Tags: specular, brdf, pbr

Most modern renderers use physically-based materials and their models are often parameterized over roughness. Since this wasn't always the case with renderers, conventional assets often don't have a notion of roughness. Instead, we see "shininess" or "specular power" as a common material parameter.

I understand that there is no exact conversion between the two, but is there a rule-of-thumb / approximate way to get roughness for a material whose specular power or shininess is known?

Comment: How about rendering a series of comparison swatches and try to fit a conversion curve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you already note, there is no clear cut interpretation/conversion for these values. I think it is even much worse: Depending on your BRDF and internal limitations (like having defined exponents ranging from 2-2048) the interpretation is *completely* different. Like suggested in the comments, it might be the best to render a series with different values and fit a conversion curve until the value looks intuitive.

A few examples I was able to find some blog posts that mention something about that topic:

- At Dontnod entertainment they use a "perceptual linear distribution".
  Sébastien Lagarde acknowledges the problem in [this blog post](https://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/feeding-a-physical-based-lighting-mode/) and writes a few notes on that.
- Brian Karis uses a squared roughness values in this [Microfacet BRDF overview](http://graphicrants.blogspot.de/2013/08/specular-brdf-reference.html). This illustrates also nicely how differently  roughness is used in different Normal Distribution Functions. Blinn-Phong power is here defined as `2/roughness^4 - 2`.
- Frostbite uses a squared remapping. ie. Roughness =  (1 − Smoothness)^2
  Details about it and their entire material system is explained in section 3.2 of Sebastien Lagarde's [writeup](http://www.frostbite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/course_notes_moving_frostbite_to_pbr.pdf).
- [This blog post](http://simonstechblog.blogspot.de/2011/12/microfacet-brdf.html) suggests to define the roughness for a Beckmann distribution from the shininess alpha as:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it will be helpful to plot the various methods on a single plot. For example - I plotted two of your links here: http://i.imgur.com/YJjIMOQ.png

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old post, put based on the comments here and the posted plot,
I fitted a curve leading to the following equation:

smoothness = 0.25 * shininess ^ 0.2